# I don't know why my java application cannot find an image

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, java-8

I have my image in the src folder, but when this part of the code is run it does not work.

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("background.png");
```

I think that the problem has to do with the image not being in the right directory, but I don't know where to put it. I am using IntelliJ and it does not have a way to add images to your project.

Comment: Put the image in the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a class directly in your src folder, or in your package, and then add this code:

```
URL urlImage = YourClassName.class.getResource("yourimage.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
```

If you have this structure: src/image and src/package/class
you can use ../ to go to the above folder. For example, using the structure above, your code will look like this:

```
URL urlImage = YourClassName.class.getResource("../yourimage.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
```

For more explanation, in file structure ../ goes one folder above. I hope I helped!